# Perl Sort Hash of Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have a hash of arrays that looks like this:

```
{ $key, [$val1, $val2] }
```

I'm trying to numerically sort by the second value of the array and print out the entire hash. I've taken a look at the Schwartzian Transform posts, but I haven't seen one that does exactly what I want. I'm also very confused by the syntax and how to map the sorted values back into the original `{$key, [$val1, $val2] }` form. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1 in 4, surely? (Not that that's much better!)

Comment: @davorg 5 questions, 1 accepted. Not sure how SO calculates this rate, it sure looks weird.

Comment: Schwartzian transform deals with sorting on computed values. You want to compute them *once* for each element not 2 * nlogn times. You already have the value you want to sort on computed `$hash->{ $key }[1]`. You do not need a Schwartzian transform.

Comment: @TLP there is a certain delay before new questions are used in that calculation.

Comment: Don't try to use a [Schwartzian Transform](http://www.google.com/search?q=Schwartzian+Transform&btnI=1) until you learn more about [Perl](http://perl.org) in general.

Comment: @TLP apologies, I assumed the check-mark below the up/down votes required at least 15 rep as well. fixed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are referring to, but this is how you implement a sort routine on an array value, inside a hash:

```
my %hash = ( 'key1' => [ 1, 2 ], 'key2' => [ 2, 3 ] );

for my $key ( sort { $hash{$a}[1] <=> $hash{$b}[1] } keys %hash ) {
    print "$key => '", join(", ", @{$hash{$key}}), "'\n";
}
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Thanks! I'm still getting used to this syntax, so apologies if this seems like an elementary question.

Answer (score 7):

I you really want to use a Schwartzian-Transform, here is a way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my %hash = (k1 => [1, 2], k2 => [24, 5], k3 => [5, 1]);
foreach(
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
        map { [$_, $hash{$_}->[1] ] } keys %hash) {
    say $_->[0],' => ',dump$hash{$_->[0]};
}
```

**output:**

```
k3 => [5, 1]
k1 => [1, 2]
k2 => [24, 5]
```

**NB:**

I just give this answer as an example of Schwartzian Transform

But as said in comment, there's no need of it in the case explained in the question, ST is cost saving when there are some computation for each element of array before sorting. For the question asked, there's no computation to be done, so don't use ST here.

Comment: Do we really need Schwartzian Transform here? It's not like `$hash{$_}->[1]` is an expensive operation.

Comment: @TLP: The OP asked specifically about a Schwartzian Transform, so I think it's in its place that he gets an example of an implementation. I do think however that an explanation for the specific case should accompany the algorithm, as these kinds of expressions can be a bit intimidating for a Perl novice.

Comment: @flesk People ask for all sorts of crazy things they don't need. =P With his data, Schwartzian Transform actually adds cost. I guess it's correct to show it, but it would be a good idea to mention that in this case it is not needed.

Comment: @TLP: That is true. The answer is better as it stands now.